# Для тягости родин жениху не отказывать стать

Tags: фразеология

Что значит эта пословица? В каких ситуациях употреблялась?

Answer (score 3):

*Для тягости родин жениху не отказывать стать.*
Прямой смысл пословицы : *жениху невеста не отказывает по причине будущих, возможно нелегких, родов*. 
Иносказательный смысл примерно такой : *невозможно обезопасить себя на всю жизнь вперед, трудности и испытания предстоят любому человеку на его пути.*
Более известная пословица (***волков бояться - в лес не ходить***)   употребляется в похожих ситуациях.

Дополнение.
Предлог "для" в сочинении Татищева в значении "из-за" :

> **«Понеже они для тягости труда не всегда к тому время имеют**, також и от любви отеческия к подданным, храня пользу оных, оное другим довольно в законах искусным и отечеству беспристрастно верным вновь потребные сочинить вверяют».

Comment: Как с таким значением пословицы соотносится значение предлога "для"?

Comment: Еще одно [обсуждение](http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=4487)

Answer (score 1):

Ну , если слово "*тягость*" понимать как что-то *трудное* , *нелёгкое* , а слово "*родины*" понимать как "*роды*" , то тогда трактовка от **Дерзкий Grantum** может быть верна . Однако попробуем сопоставить слово "*тягость*" со словом "*тяжба*" , т.е. *судебная тяжба* , а , в более широком смысле , какой-то *спор* , *конфликт* . А слово "*родины*" попробуем сопоставить с украинским словом "*родина*"(ударение на 2-м слоге) , которое на русский язык переводится как "*семья*" . Тогда вырисовывается другой смысл этой поговорки : "**невесте не должно отказывать жениху , если семьи** (их семьи) **конфликтуют между собой** . Поговорка подразумевает протест против патриархально-домостроевского уклада , а в широком смысле , типа , как *не плясать под чужую дудочку* , *своя голова не плечах* или *своя рубашка ближе к телу* . Слово "*родина*" , в значении , соответствующем украинскому "*семья*" , могло сохраняться в старой русской речи как рудимент более древнего общеславянского говора .

Comment: **Родины** (роды) - мн. число.
>Ф. В. Ростопчин. Ох, французы! (1812)  
Радость их была оттого велика, что Настасья Матвевна (матушка Луки Андреича) шестнадцать лет не рожала **после родин первого сына**...  
**После родин** бабушка повивальная хотела ребенку впустить в рот капельку белого вина, но ошибкой ей подали французской водки...  
Много при сем случае было искательства и происков: о иной бабе просил прикащик, о другой ловчий, о третьей казначей; но просьбы остались втуне, и **до родин барин отговаривался** одним словом: «посмотрим»;

Answer (score 1):

Сие не есть пока ответ, просто комментарий перерос собственно комметарий и по размеру и по смыслу.

[[@следопыт](/users/2568/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82)](/users/2568/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82)
Трактовку Груманта я не комментирую, ибо изначально из пальца высосана, а он здравые рассуждения не воспринимает.

Но Вы тоже, простите, не лучше. Какой, к шуту, протест против уклада, если по вашей трактовке как раз и утверждается домострой?
Предложенное переосмысление Вами терминов тоже никакой критики не выдерживает.

У меня есть некоторые предположения, каким был исходный смысл поговорки - и почему и как он ныне скрыт. Но воздержусь излагать пока не будет хотя бы внутреннего убеждения в правильности.

Копать же, думаю, надо в направлении "тяжесть родин" = "количество детей". Основанием к тому может служить формы типа "она была тяжела первенцем" в значении "беременна".